# How to convert an svg to the 'path://...' format for using within echarts-liquidfill

Tags: svg, echarts

I have the following svg,

```
<svg
version="1.1"
id="Layer_1"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
x="0px"
y="0px"
width="100%"
viewBox="0 0 500 637"
enable-background="new 0 0 500 637"
xml:space="preserve"
>
<path
    fill="#ffffff"
    opacity="000000"
    stroke="none"
    d="
    M1.000000,185.000000 
C1.000000,123.346764 1.000000,62.193523 1.000000,1.020141 
C167.616653,1.020141 334.233307,1.020141 500.924988,1.020141 
C500.924988,213.236694 500.924988,425.473419 500.924988,637.855103 
C334.333405,637.855103 167.666733,637.855103 1.000000,637.855103 
C1.000000,487.099854 1.000000,336.299927 1.000000,185.000000 
    M437.023651,357.500000 
C437.023682,264.855377 437.051453,172.210709 436.935272,79.566216 
C436.929901,75.298859 437.834290,73.342255 442.419647,73.934158 
C445.041534,74.272621 447.754730,74.144867 450.407562,73.956284 
C457.434631,73.456734 461.935150,65.893639 458.768036,59.816845 
C456.785797,56.013527 453.365967,54.911766 449.151886,54.921280 
C411.161072,55.007088 373.169983,54.970287 335.178955,54.970417 
C238.201859,54.970745 141.224762,54.969334 44.247665,54.976765 
C37.141014,54.977310 34.120346,57.536850 33.983326,63.566376 
C33.837585,69.979607 37.363068,73.652016 44.042191,73.980614 
C45.704494,74.062386 47.374142,73.995293 49.040413,73.995956 
C55.993931,73.998726 55.995934,73.998634 55.995953,80.994514 
C55.996330,242.123108 55.995022,403.251709 55.997837,564.380310 
C55.998177,583.730103 70.341263,598.003418 89.775375,598.003845 
C194.750580,598.005981 299.725891,597.930176 404.700867,598.081299 
C421.394196,598.105347 437.217041,583.730469 437.141754,565.950500 
C436.848907,496.801392 437.023193,427.650330 437.023651,357.500000 
   M184.500000,603.992676 
C257.825714,603.992676 331.151428,603.963928 404.477112,604.009705 
C427.108856,604.023865 443.161652,584.968384 443.134064,565.419617 
C442.909393,406.266815 443.008362,247.113525 443.008911,87.960388 
C443.008911,86.627167 443.127258,85.281425 442.986694,83.963242 
C442.660156,80.901024 444.019318,80.169388 446.974884,79.850136 
C451.005859,79.414696 455.155457,78.519508 458.846252,76.894753 
C463.259491,74.951950 466.812286,67.033371 465.850647,62.420143 
C464.554596,56.202911 461.352539,51.072014 454.985718,49.321239 
C450.901306,48.198086 446.449829,48.074703 442.162628,48.072659 
C316.006714,48.012463 189.850754,48.008335 63.694820,48.064709 
C56.569374,48.067894 49.433964,48.516422 42.321411,49.016697 
C32.917454,49.678135 27.748222,55.653801 27.999573,65.205101 
C28.202894,72.931259 35.195202,79.845169 43.384525,79.924454 
C50.712292,79.995407 50.001457,79.692642 50.001858,86.819443 
C50.010853,246.472549 49.968891,406.125671 50.082809,565.778687 
C50.092606,579.507019 56.323814,590.435974 67.960114,597.845825 
C71.671318,600.209106 76.030258,601.555115 80.092827,603.366516 
C80.378899,602.739807 80.664970,602.113159 80.951042,601.486450 
C79.627510,600.820862 78.317955,600.125488 76.977371,599.496216 
C74.577972,598.369934 71.999146,597.538635 69.775948,596.138489 
C56.436695,587.737610 52.029377,574.876831 52.029007,559.908752 
C52.025101,402.088837 52.026581,244.268906 52.026592,86.448982 
C52.026592,77.133842 52.026638,77.133850 42.497986,77.002502 
C36.033131,76.913399 30.600168,71.638908 29.982210,65.226524 
C29.234467,57.467377 36.086552,50.848610 44.732784,50.862019 
C179.221039,51.070602 313.709686,51.007885 448.198273,51.008724 
C449.364777,51.008732 450.539856,50.931217 451.696411,51.041756 
C458.151215,51.658703 462.923523,56.888084 463.002472,63.372395 
C463.115417,72.650581 458.156952,77.441025 447.897308,77.965683 
C440.997009,78.318542 440.995392,78.318550 440.995361,85.029274 
C440.995026,244.515732 440.857971,404.002472 441.160736,563.488342 
C441.200592,584.479980 425.058838,602.053040 402.425323,602.027588 
C298.600922,601.910706 194.776352,601.976074 90.951836,601.976074 
C88.635468,601.976074 86.319107,601.976074 84.002739,601.976074 
C85.274796,602.975525 86.645653,603.776428 88.019569,603.781677 
C119.846184,603.904297 151.673126,603.940430 184.500000,603.992676 
z"
/>
<path
    fill="#E7ECEC"
    opacity="1.000000"
    stroke="none"
    d="
  M437.023682,358.000000 
C437.023193,427.650330 436.848907,496.801392 437.141754,565.950500 
C437.217041,583.730469 421.394196,598.105347 404.700867,598.081299 
C299.725891,597.930176 194.750580,598.005981 89.775375,598.003845 
C70.341263,598.003418 55.998177,583.730103 55.997837,564.380310 
C55.995022,403.251709 55.996330,242.123108 55.995953,80.994514 
C55.995934,73.998634 55.993931,73.998726 49.040413,73.995956 
C47.374142,73.995293 45.704494,74.062386 44.042191,73.980614 
C37.363068,73.652016 33.837585,69.979607 33.983326,63.566376 
C34.120346,57.536850 37.141014,54.977310 44.247665,54.976765 
C141.224762,54.969334 238.201859,54.970745 335.178955,54.970417 
C373.169983,54.970287 411.161072,55.007088 449.151886,54.921280 
C453.365967,54.911766 456.785797,56.013527 458.768036,59.816845 
C461.935150,65.893639 457.434631,73.456734 450.407562,73.956284 
C447.754730,74.144867 445.041534,74.272621 442.419647,73.934158 
C437.834290,73.342255 436.929901,75.298859 436.935272,79.566216 
C437.051453,172.210709 437.023682,264.855377 437.023682,358.000000 
  M435.006104,402.500000 
C435.006104,294.691833 435.006104,186.883698 435.006104,79.075539 
C435.006104,77.909142 435.120972,76.729164 434.984802,75.578896 
C434.583588,72.189926 435.795624,70.703308 439.411804,70.958313 
C443.225189,71.227226 447.075012,71.102806 450.904175,70.989677 
C454.892181,70.871864 456.941711,68.711594 457.018524,64.689888 
C457.127991,58.954956 454.717438,56.991566 447.448120,56.991421 
C313.812439,56.988701 180.176758,56.988914 46.541088,56.995773 
C45.045437,56.995850 43.477211,56.820213 42.068417,57.196583 
C38.526932,58.142712 36.179855,60.445141 36.100983,64.257729 
C36.030163,67.680847 39.649616,70.889069 43.393124,71.000336 
C46.056847,71.079498 48.724770,71.017387 51.390816,71.018372 
C58.974052,71.021172 58.975849,71.021172 58.975868,78.745148 
C58.976227,239.707825 58.976116,400.670502 58.976376,561.633179 
C58.976379,563.799316 58.935455,565.966614 58.989201,568.131470 
C59.327820,581.770630 72.699364,595.008301 86.257271,595.010498 
C193.399094,595.028015 300.540924,595.033264 407.682678,594.946777 
C410.585541,594.944458 413.745667,594.415833 416.345703,593.195251 
C428.214630,587.623413 434.918823,578.222534 434.951111,564.962463 
C435.082184,511.141907 435.005890,457.320862 435.006104,402.500000 
  z"
/>
<path
    fill="#E7ECEC"
    opacity="1.000000"
    stroke="none"
    d="
  M184.000000,603.992676 
C151.673126,603.940430 119.846184,603.904297 88.019569,603.781677 
C86.645653,603.776428 85.274796,602.975525 84.002739,601.976074 
C86.319107,601.976074 88.635468,601.976074 90.951836,601.976074 
C194.776352,601.976074 298.600922,601.910706 402.425323,602.027588 
C425.058838,602.053040 441.200592,584.479980 441.160736,563.488342 
C440.857971,404.002472 440.995026,244.515732 440.995361,85.029274 
C440.995392,78.318550 440.997009,78.318542 447.897308,77.965683 
C458.156952,77.441025 463.115417,72.650581 463.002472,63.372395 
C462.923523,56.888084 458.151215,51.658703 451.696411,51.041756 
C450.539856,50.931217 449.364777,51.008732 448.198273,51.008724 
C313.709686,51.007885 179.221039,51.070602 44.732784,50.862019 
C36.086552,50.848610 29.234467,57.467377 29.982210,65.226524 
C30.600168,71.638908 36.033131,76.913399 42.497986,77.002502 
C52.026638,77.133850 52.026592,77.133842 52.026592,86.448982 
C52.026581,244.268906 52.025101,402.088837 52.029007,559.908752 
C52.029377,574.876831 56.436695,587.737610 69.775948,596.138489 
C71.999146,597.538635 74.577972,598.369934 76.977371,599.496216 
C78.317955,600.125488 79.627510,600.820862 80.951042,601.486450 
C80.664970,602.113159 80.378899,602.739807 80.092827,603.366516 
C76.030258,601.555115 71.671318,600.209106 67.960114,597.845825 
C56.323814,590.435974 50.092606,579.507019 50.082809,565.778687 
C49.968891,406.125671 50.010853,246.472549 50.001858,86.819443 
C50.001457,79.692642 50.712292,79.995407 43.384525,79.924454 
C35.195202,79.845169 28.202894,72.931259 27.999573,65.205101 
C27.748222,55.653801 32.917454,49.678135 42.321411,49.016697 
C49.433964,48.516422 56.569374,48.067894 63.694820,48.064709 
C189.850754,48.008335 316.006714,48.012463 442.162628,48.072659 
C446.449829,48.074703 450.901306,48.198086 454.985718,49.321239 
C461.352539,51.072014 464.554596,56.202911 465.850647,62.420143 
C466.812286,67.033371 463.259491,74.951950 458.846252,76.894753 
C455.155457,78.519508 451.005859,79.414696 446.974884,79.850136 
C444.019318,80.169388 442.660156,80.901024 442.986694,83.963242 
C443.127258,85.281425 443.008911,86.627167 443.008911,87.960388 
C443.008362,247.113525 442.909393,406.266815 443.134064,565.419617 
C443.161652,584.968384 427.108856,604.023865 404.477112,604.009705 
C331.151428,603.963928 257.825714,603.992676 184.000000,603.992676 
  z"
/>
<path
    fill="#fafafa"
    opacity="000000"
    stroke="none"
    d="
  M435.006104,403.000000 
C435.005890,457.320862 435.082184,511.141907 434.951111,564.962463 
C434.918823,578.222534 428.214630,587.623413 416.345703,593.195251 
C413.745667,594.415833 410.585541,594.944458 407.682678,594.946777 
C300.540924,595.033264 193.399094,595.028015 86.257271,595.010498 
C72.699364,595.008301 59.327820,581.770630 58.989201,568.131470 
C58.935455,565.966614 58.976379,563.799316 58.976376,561.633179 
C58.976116,400.670502 58.976227,239.707825 58.975868,78.745148 
C58.975849,71.021172 58.974052,71.021172 51.390816,71.018372 
C48.724770,71.017387 46.056847,71.079498 43.393124,71.000336 
C39.649616,70.889069 36.030163,67.680847 36.100983,64.257729 
C36.179855,60.445141 38.526932,58.142712 42.068417,57.196583 
C43.477211,56.820213 45.045437,56.995850 46.541088,56.995773 
C180.176758,56.988914 313.812439,56.988701 447.448120,56.991421 
C454.717438,56.991566 457.127991,58.954956 457.018524,64.689888 
C456.941711,68.711594 454.892181,70.871864 450.904175,70.989677 
C447.075012,71.102806 443.225189,71.227226 439.411804,70.958313 
C435.795624,70.703308 434.583588,72.189926 434.984802,75.578896 
C435.120972,76.729164 435.006104,77.909142 435.006104,79.075539 
C435.006104,186.883698 435.006104,294.691833 435.006104,403.000000 
  z"
/>
</svg>
```

I'm using [echarts-liquidfill](https://github.com/ecomfe/echarts-liquidfill) to create some charts and I need my charts to be contained inside specific shapes so I'm using [this feature of the library](https://github.com/ecomfe/echarts-liquidfill#shape).

```
var option = {
series: [{
    type: 'liquidFill',
    data: [0.6, 0.55, 0.4, 0.25],
    radius: '60%',
    outline: {
        show: false
    },
    backgroundStyle: {
        borderColor: '#156ACF',
        borderWidth: 1,
        shadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)',
        shadowBlur: 20
    },
    shape: 'path://M367.855,428.202c-3.674-1.385-7.452-1.966-11.146-1.794c0.659- 
  2.922,0.844-5.85,0.58-8.719 c-0.937-10.407-7.663-19.864-18.063-23.834c-10.697-4.043- 
   22.298-1.168-29.902,6.403c3.015,0.026,6.074,0.594,9.035,1.728 
  c13.626,5.151,20.465,20.379,15.32,34.004c-1.905,5.02-5.177,9.115-9.22,12.05c- 
  6.951,4.992-16.19,6.536-24.777,3.271 c-13.625-5.137-20.471-20.371-15.32-34.004c0.673- 
    1.768,1.523-3.423,2.526-4.992h-0.014c0,0,0,0,0,0.014 c4.386-6.853,8.145- 
 14.279,11.146-22.187c23.294-61.505-7.689-130.278-69.215-153.579c-61.532-23.293- 
    130.279,7.69-153.579,69.202 c-6.371,16.785-8.679,34.097-7.426,50.901c0.026,0.554,0.079,1.121,0.132,1.688c4.973,57.107,41.767,109.148,98.945,130.793 
 c58.162,22.008,121.303,6.529,162.839-34.465c7.103-6.893,17.826-9.444,27.679- 
  5.719c11.858,4.491,18.565,16.6,16.719,28.643 c4.438-3.126,8.033-7.564,10.117- 
 13.045C389.751,449.992,382.411,433.709,367.855,428.202z',
    label: {
        position: ['38%', '40%'],
        formatter: function() {
            return 'ECharts\nLiquid Fill';
        },
        fontSize: 40,
        color: '#D94854'
    }
}]
```

};

as you can see the shape: takes a string svg that starts with 'path://'. How can I convert an svg to this style?

I have already tried using adobe illustrator. I uploaded the png i have and exported the svg from the adobe express and then that svg to illustrator and unified all paths and go to the menu Edit->Copy, but the result is still not in the format I need.

another thing I tried which got my really close is to just copy the content of the path inside my svg and append it to this string, 'path://' which works with the chart but then because it's transparent, the chart content only shows on the outline.

So even if someone can help me find out how to set the opacity/fill on this svg, I'll be able to create the chart I need.

> path://M430.78,11.79c-1.98-3.8-5.4-4.91-9.62-4.9-37.99.09-75.98.05-113.97.05-96.98,0-193.95,0-290.93,0-7.11,0-10.13,2.56-10.26,8.59-.15,6.41,3.38,10.09,10.06,10.41,1.66.08,3.33.01,5,.02q6.95,0,6.96,7c0,161.13,0,322.26,0,483.39,0,19.35,14.34,33.62,33.78,33.62,104.98,0,209.95-.07,314.93.08,16.69.02,32.52-14.35,32.44-32.13-.29-69.15-.12-138.3-.12-207.95,0-93.14.03-185.79-.09-278.43,0-4.27.9-6.22,5.48-5.63,2.62.34,5.34.21,7.99.02,7.03-.5,11.53-8.06,8.36-14.14ZM422.91,22.96c-3.83.11-7.68.24-11.49-.03-3.62-.26-4.83,1.23-4.43,4.62.14,1.15.02,2.33.02,3.5v323.42c0,54.82.08,108.64-.05,162.46-.03,13.26-6.74,22.66-18.61,28.23-2.6,1.22-5.76,1.75-8.66,1.75-107.14.09-214.28.08-321.43.06-13.56,0-26.93-13.24-27.27-26.88-.05-2.16-.01-4.33-.01-6.5,0-160.96,0-321.93,0-482.89q0-7.72-7.59-7.73c-2.67,0-5.33.06-8-.02-3.74-.11-7.36-3.32-7.29-6.74.08-3.81,2.43-6.12,5.97-7.06,1.41-.38,2.98-.2,4.47-.2,133.64,0,267.27,0,400.91,0,7.27,0,9.68,1.96,9.57,7.7-.08,4.02-2.13,6.18-6.11,6.3Z M437.86,14.4c-1.3-6.22-4.5-11.35-10.86-13.1-4.08-1.12-8.54-1.25-12.82-1.25C288.02-.01,161.86-.02,35.7.04c-7.13,0-14.26.45-21.37.95C4.93,1.65-.24,7.63,0,17.18c.2,7.73,7.2,14.64,15.38,14.72,7.33.07,6.62-.23,6.62,6.9,0,159.65-.03,319.31.08,478.96,0,13.73,6.24,24.66,17.88,32.07,3.71,2.36,8.07,3.71,12.13,5.52.29-.63.57-1.25.86-1.88-1.32-.67-2.63-1.36-3.97-1.99-2.4-1.13-4.98-1.96-7.2-3.36-13.34-8.4-17.75-21.26-17.75-36.23,0-157.82,0-315.64,0-473.46q0-9.32-9.53-9.45c-6.46-.09-11.9-5.36-12.52-11.78-.75-7.76,6.1-14.38,14.75-14.36,134.49.21,268.98.15,403.47.15,1.17,0,2.34-.08,3.5.03,6.45.62,11.23,5.85,11.31,12.33.11,9.28-4.85,14.07-15.11,14.59q-6.9.35-6.9,7.06c0,159.49-.14,318.97.17,478.46.04,20.99-16.1,38.56-38.74,38.54-103.82-.12-207.65-.05-311.47-.05h-6.95c1.27,1,2.64,1.8,4.02,1.81,31.83.12,63.65.16,95.98.21,73.83,0,147.15-.03,220.48.02,22.63.01,38.68-19.04,38.66-38.59-.22-159.15-.13-318.31-.13-477.46,0-1.33.12-2.68-.02-4-.33-3.06,1.03-3.79,3.99-4.11,4.03-.44,8.18-1.33,11.87-2.96,4.41-1.94,7.97-9.86,7-14.47Z

Comment: You're dealing with a compound path - including many subpaths. Apparently liquid charts need a closed and solid shape to apply a sort of clip-path/mask. You can decompose compound paths to their subpaths via `Object > Compound path > Release` then you can use the inner shape as the clipping path (so you can remove other paths and rewrite the svg again). Now you have a single solid shape that should work fine.

Comment: @herrstrietzel, thanks for your comment. could you please post it as an answer so i can select it and upvote? also give an example so we can see how you would do this? and what do you exactly mean by Object > Command path > Release, what application are these menu options referring to? Thanks!